# Syntax highlighting in egui Rust

Tags: user-interface, rust, syntax-highlighting, egui

I'm writing a text editor in Rust using egui. I am trying to implement syntax highlighting,
so I followed the example in [the demo](https://egui.rs). It works there, so I thought it might be useful. But I am getting an error that `syntax_highlighting` is not found in the crate root. I have syntect and egui both installed at their latest versions and have them
as dependencies.

```rust
let mut theme = crate::syntax_highlighting::CodeTheme::from_memory(ui.ctx());
ui.collapsing("Theme", |ui| {
    ui.group(|ui| {
        theme.ui(ui);
        theme.clone().store_in_memory(ui.ctx());
    });
});


let mut layouter = |ui: &egui::Ui, string: &str, wrap_width: f32| {
    let mut layout_job = 
        crate::syntax_highlighting::highlight(ui.ctx(), &theme, string, self.language);
    layout_job.wrap.max_width = wrap_width;
    ui.fonts().layout_job(layout_job)
};
```

In particular, it is these lines that raise the error that `syntax_highlighting` is not found in the crate root. In case it's useful, here is all my code:
https://pastebin.com/mHDhLhSR

**I want to implement syntax highlighting to my egui application, but I get the error that `syntax_highlighting` is not found in the crate root, which the only example I found used.**

Answer (score 2):

The `crate::` means `syntax_highlighting` is a member of the `egui_demo_lib` crate itself. In this case, you'll [find it right here](https://github.com/emilk/egui/blob/3c685d7bf6a36bda9ffbee36ee822b4205b29b36/egui_demo_lib/src/syntax_highlighting.rs).